# transform syntax and structures containing vectors c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the syntax of the function `std::transform`. So, I have a structure `AirportInfo` that contains information about the airports. Every structure is then arranged in a dictionary, so that they have unique IDs. In the structure there is a vector of pairs `m_routes` which contains the ID of the destination airport and also whether the flight is direct or not. (In this case only direct flight are to be considered, because all non-direct flights have already been deleted, so the second item of the pair will always be 0). The function `calculateDistanceBetween` returns the distance between 2 airports, by knowing their coordinates, that are being stored also in the structure in `pos`. Now I have to calculate the distance for every route, but I cannot get over the syntax :( Any Help will be appreciated, Thank you!

This piece of code works

```
// Calculates the distance between two points on earth specified by longitude/latitude.
// Function taken and adapted from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22488/Distance-using-Longitiude-and-latitude-using-c
float calculateDistanceBetween(float lat1, float long1, float lat2, float long2)
{
    // main code inside the class
    float dlat1 = lat1 * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);

    float dlong1 = long1 * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);
    float dlat2 = lat2 * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);
    float dlong2 = long2 * ((float)M_PI / 180.0f);

    float dLong = dlong1 - dlong2;
    float dLat = dlat1 - dlat2;

    float aHarv = pow(sin(dLat / 2.0f), 2.0f) + cos(dlat1) * cos(dlat2) * pow(sin(dLong / 2), 2);
    float cHarv = 2 * atan2(sqrt(aHarv), sqrt(1.0f - aHarv));
    // earth's radius from wikipedia varies between 6,356.750 km and 6,378.135 km
    // The IUGG value for the equatorial radius of the Earth is 6378.137 km
    const float earth = 6378.137f;
    return earth * cHarv;
}

struct AirportInfo
{
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_city;
    std::string m_country;
    float pos[2]; // x: latitude, y: longitude

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> m_routes; // dest_id + numStops
    std::vector<float> m_routeLengths;
    float m_averageRouteLength;
};
```

Here is what causes the trouble:

```
//- For each route in AirportInfo::m_routes, calculate the distance between start and destination. Store the results in AirportInfo::m_routeLengths. Use std::transform() and calculateDistanceBetween().
void calculateDistancePerRoute(std::map<int, AirportInfo>& airportInfo)
{   //loop all structures 
    for(int i = 0; i < airportInfo.size(); i++ ){
                        // START                        END                                         SAVE 
        std::transform(airportInfo[i].pos[0], airportInfo[i].pos[1], /*...*/ , airportInfo[i].m_routeLengths.begin(), 
                        calculateDistanceBetween);

    }
    std::cout << "Calculate distance for each route" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::transform` works on iterators transforming ranges (e.g. vectors, arrays, etc). Did you want to iterate over map elements and calculate distance for each entry? Then you pass `airportInfo.begin()`, `airportInfo.end()` instead of those pos variables, and then the function receives an `std::pair<int, AirportInfo>`, which you can work on. Besides, it seems like a `std::vector` will work instead of `std::map`, as it seems like your id range starts from zero and is contiguous.

Comment: Hint: For every `AirportInfo` (call it `src`) in `airportInfo`, apply `std::transform` to every element of `src.m_routes` and store the result in `src.m_routeElements`. The actual transformation should return `calculateDistanceBetween(src, dest)` where `dest` is the argument to the `transform` functor/lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::back_inserter(airportInfo[i].m_routeLengths)` (and if performance is important, reserve vector sizes in advance), instead of `airportInfo[i].m_routeLengths.begin()`. Also, iterating by index when there is nothing "enforcing" that the indecies in the map are going from `0...map.size()` is not safe, you should prefer using a vector for the shown usecase.

I think this is something like what you want:

```cpp
void calculateDistancePerRoute(std::map<int, AirportInfo>& airportInfo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < airportInfo.size(); i++ )
    {
        float currentPosX = airportInfo.at(i).pos[0];
        float currentPosY = airportInfo.at(i).pos[1];
        std::transform(airportInfo.begin(), airportInfo.end(), std::back_inserter(airportInfo.at(i).m_routeLengths), [&] (const auto& otherAirport)
        {
           return calculateDistanceBetween(currentPosX, currentPosY, otherAirport.second.pos[0], otherAirport.second.pos[1]);
        });
    }
}
```

[Example in Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqRDWIAMA6A7IxBGAnI7A2TTVTAJlIA4BWAGgBsQByUxmgWxEwxoDsnFWAeyasALv0YBKGtHBQYUABYgAxoIAmAUwCi6gJajBAJxp6QEAGaCeogMoqAhnU2cALDQBWIUvQc9QKgCkpABCwSE0AM6aziqietbmmjzqAMKCdACubHyYNMnqADJ6PJoActkARppGnBQ0AA6CkQYJPOlZOZyNza3WxaUVbNW1mPXRsfHWtqIORqId2blRMZpxbTNzogPlVTV1UbPzi115kUfbJbvD%2B2PSkYKZRioujMEAzCUqWVoA1IHvVJsBwNAHaQKIACCHy%2BP00/0BADc1oYjGCIdDSJ8eN9Mn8AaknMBjAZFGx0VCYTi4QjUpl4nQDABPCmY7G4/GAlTA0SKVlUjnwgkJc5GTQOcnvcGUqEAellv0JdBUmToDlEmkiv158P05z8L1%2B1VEAHdNMltSbBL8miVRFrrL9xfNFL9Ig01noLHpNOojUzfnRrMADHjNLK1fFRGHkBj5b8AGKZHFTHjahxwC1%2BP0OdQgjV%2BixGQRsX6KUSiBogeUm2vINRaBrFjwo%2Bsl2WQ%2BZ6b6a2XkVwUCiygAien1OM0AFpMi1/JPCsHWmHJ9nJ5HQ1pp7PgJOglCLEH1b9HMrVerNKPxy8QppTeaeJZD6JA%2Bq8r8D4Ij0H/G%2BP1/1T475PoGwakJIGKBKgYRQr8sG/PGwIlMeGjwiULR/Dqx5qpEkQYnBQGfs%2B6iRpgCLDi%2BoikQAVL8UB/qIkgALIAPoAAoAJLwb8YwoIgFjge80HQjBcH0b8xHBqRALkd%2BwDUbRj6EUxbGcQqPHIHxAlCfhYnEQBZEUaQvw0XRT7KRxXHqZpALaaJwESf4RnSSBjnGQp9Hmap3EULx/E2RBImwbpC7%2BAZDlyb8k7ibJpD%2BYFBFHkUR7OXplGRdFAFxcJkI6cBDgABJzIiBlNCaECzhASXPgqpAafxNC/LVmn/KEyGRJVJGSG5ajtalYFuaV5UlJVIXAFxYENWBWW5YRx6FUYxXOUZNHqn4pDlQAjvMEAFUV0hultogQJgdXpbtC2SFpeFwfGzq8mAjBakYuZ6DO77FqWJp6HAegevoDi/Iicw%2Blqxpmha%2BA0O8VD4GgVCIL8cCltmvyQ%2B8qAUMgmDQ4j5LxfGAAqijwuxACqADi5OA04mTwlYRjasTTobZk6okk4vzPfob2CBYjPwtoWyumOqPo5j2OoLj12wWoPDnAlz53a6zn4GLWPoxY01wWK0ZGGmSvdfNiJZZBw4BZCoqZHEvyQnoRhNPM7E8FYEFQdLbqiOoIAgKKJRjWwzE8BKmha7B5xez7ohGH7vwByozKhx7Ee%2B6FcePDYRgsoJ7tiU0uFUCEsVUGbgnwQqAAeIAURumgNUyVeyTX5v4eH3vInExgEq3IANA4dvCjYDV2uiUqx8xxb0pqNll%2BJmqiMxeh%2BuEvw8NkMyCA0uHxd37eogS9FgmPE8aoUyTALyuHZ/FYkBw4yLPcAmgAEqPCfZ%2B8onRY%2BikgOCIvx5OBVJGC8Y5ZgTlYjUF%2Bk9yqe29sCUEgI7QNVtvbYwognYuylMEfAvw%2B6oMds7QQV1KSoBLkJOMsoooJmME6BwKhXTH1QmmFBDt0GELgePV%2BmoGoniAeefm4lQEGnhGDe8Hsti4J/loc4JR1RtGQL8deYoBFikiKqe0vwkIsLQRg4QIAA6MNPv4C%2BCjSbRCTt7KOfhIj0zYBALqKNeFng1JeMB15bzgwfJIWMUJER/z9E44BrjhEQKMFAjUMCI7wIHqIZBdtWG6PRKQHBeCEmEPAiQ2yQVjAQDtJogyiBp56FpLg%2BJOjCHIBaAAL00PYop4Rl4ZJynBSCWT8IK2PE8MUNhWLNAABoGVSeUqwyB1S5O8XnQIBdCnF0TjNI8KojDdNEL0yIABNQZZSCEjLGXoCZzQpkhEwFMsh7sW6wJAFYuWtidpbLYSM6oIYvENSGdswQyACj2Iat3SodC4ALzljUDURhbn4Pue83Z3iDFcKMefRQkR9qHOwSc2ist5YOHpIIbBvxBA6iMNo%2BYTT2ktLdvFYlnNbxPDTIE88wSJw3jvMkCAizlmrL6TwrpyQVnNDWQ1XFxN8V3MqWsaw6hkCTOmScvleKCWiGFbLMVEqjknOIc04lptVX4VNq7M2MpbY2Fjn3Lxrs2myt0bg45V81U2zueahwsUrX4QcCdJVMzyLOS4IUx1cFnXioOQXY5xcDKesTvav1%2BcQhuuDRgUNLr/WRpRUtGN3qw4XPgbSJBNqwWJNHq8%2B0rSzlwW7sCTMzFe52wgIgF5mBpCFtTVEjMmgy14OOi8qa8VtUpoAaeIJQjwGQK4aC1hCKTbbwuWoektICSlLBZEUZR1EBQs4ZPWFF9DlRoJNO4ITlyBTsBDO4d87K1LsMe/eFhzA3usBNO7uBQ6CJx1lS34XryGkKkPQJgVBWB8EYAIGgwhGCpAaa1B4TxDQfBYDQcQv6pDSAQPDD9jBXDfokP%2BkQUQkBQYkNIWQsAFAQGUGoNgDQ9DOBMGYZlJYSNkdUGqfwPkq3ejoMCyI5hKiocqLIzOTBMCsCI2wLlAB5HgdB64wZoFoYE/hnCof0GKdYyJWPic0OXNYk9UN2hiKhxklRnqZ3SFoHjYho4cEYLx6QVgbD2CcC4TA7gvB5DowEYDEQdOscgNIDeqYlOTnDtJIIoRwjEEioJ94rAJgojaEkFIJxlgFB2EMEY3Q859HaBkJYyXeipgS3sUYKxJgbAuLF7oEX1jTAuDlm4eX9THHS6cQ4WxKtJZrVER4zwXATQYIwL9vBUMAfLhQfAk58CuCwn4MamNeK0V0AYGhEGGrpGI6RmoLV3g1sVC5sQ2HpDE1zPsL58Gq1deQ%2BwEACGf1/oA%2BFzD0GBA4fw8oV%2BDR6SmHMER6jtx8j6FRN4Gglm7AnhcPUE0z0qxmffV1nrF2hBMA%2BKRL6vJfgDaGyNsboVJsaS2zBy6NBdtaFqF847rAODnb6%2Bh1jVbbuwZoIdxDYXeviau1h7HcGQDYGwMgUg7OfK4HeIOSgqBIZdcgxwT1DPLvoapzj4XKHGeS%2B2zQe%2BLREiuCAA%3D)

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want. I only cannot really understand why you are using `.second` in `otherAirport.second.pos[0/1]`. Thank you!

Comment: @Nikola `.second` is needed, because the iterator of `std::map` is a key-value pair.

Comment: Okay, I understand

Comment: It turns out there is a small problem. I think in `transform` the beginning needs to `airportInfo[i].m_routes.begin()` and also the same for the end condition, because otherwise the vector `m_routesLengths` gets filled with as many values as there are pairs in general. (But it needs to be only as many as there are pairs in `m_routes`). However, I cannot compile it if I try `airportInfo[i].m_routes.begin()` :(

Comment: Just replace the `for` loop with one that loops on the routes.